# Ошибки при использовании TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

При проверке работоспособности TensorFlow с помощью `python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"`
Выводятся ошибки:

```
nessie27@nessie27-MS-7A38:~$ python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"
2024-02-22 14:41:07.960478: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:9261] Unable to register cuDNN factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuDNN when one has already been registered
2024-02-22 14:41:07.960512: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_fft.cc:607] Unable to register cuFFT factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuFFT when one has already been registered
2024-02-22 14:41:07.961460: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1515] Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuBLAS when one has already been registered
2024-02-22 14:41:07.968017: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2024-02-22 14:41:08.941686: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
2024-02-22 14:41:09.588547: I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_executor.cc:901] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
2024-02-22 14:41:09.620514: I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_executor.cc:901] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
2024-02-22 14:41:09.620742: I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_executor.cc:901] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
```

Операционная система: Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Все эти библиотеки `cuda` и прочее ставили через `pip install tensorflow[and-cuda]` или отдельно? Я так понимаю, рекомендуется отдельно не ставить, а ставить вместе через этот пакет.

Comment: с помощью этой команды и ставила pip install tensorflow[and-cuda]

Comment: А до того не ставили вручную `cuda`? По-хорошему нужно с нуля как-то попробовать в чистое окружение поставить.

Comment: До этого не ставила

Comment: Тогда не знаю. Гуглить по этой ошибке, но там ничего внятного кроме этих советов, что я уже привёл

Comment: (((((((((((((((